# Do I get paid for apps put on Stack Apps?

Tags: support, stackapps

Someone suggested me to develop an application using Stack Exchange API, and put it in Stack Apps. Do I get paid for apps put on Stack Apps?

Answer (score 8):

No. The idea is really its a way for SE users to share the tools they built to scratch an itch. All you get is the love and adoration of the small masses.

Answer (score 4):

No, we don't get paid for any content we post in Stack Exchange, no matter on what site.

Comment: But I can post an advertisement about my commercial app on Stack App, can't I?

Comment: @Ooker only if the app is using Stack Exchange API and is useful somehow for SE, otherwise it's just spam like on every site. But yes, if the app meets those criteria, one can "advertise" it there and in theory get some downloads this way. No direct payment, but one might get few dollars this way after some years. (There aren't really many visitors there.)

Comment: So in theory it's possible, right?

Comment: @Ooker see my comment edit. :)

Comment: I think this can be added to the answer

Comment: @Ooker not sure, that's not exactly what has been asked. I'll give it some thought before editing and update you in case I choose to edit. Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly what has been asked? Isn't the question asking for the possibility of getting paid, and it answers that it's possible?